# istringstream in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, stringstream

I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid here, but I can't quite figure out what it is.  When I try to run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 string s("hello");

 istringstream input(s, istringstream::in);

 string s2;
 input >> s2;

 cout << s;
}
```

I get this error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x100016200: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

The only thing I can think of is that I allocated s2 on the stack, but I thought strings manage their own content on the heap.  Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks,

helixed

EDIT: Fixed the last line of main, where `cout << s` should have been `cout << s2`. It runs without error if I initialized s2 to "hi", but not otherwise.  Is this just a weird gcc compilation problem?

Comment: That looks fine to me and runs successfully on my machine. That's the exact input file you're using? What OS/compiler?

Comment: Well it isn't an input file. I'm trying to use a string as the input.

Comment: Oh, sorry, and I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.3 (10D573) and the default compiler in Xcode (I think it's gcc, but I'm not sure).

Comment: What does g++ -v produce

Comment: Hi, sorry for the last reply.  The output is a little too long to post here, but for some reason compiling in g++ seemed to solve the problem.  Any idea what it is about Xcode that's making everything so screwy? Thanks - helixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me.

But I have never done this:

```
istringstream input(s, istringstream::in);
```

Try

```
istringstream input(s);
```

Comment: `ios_base::in` is the default for the `which` argument, so it shouldn't matter

Comment: @helixed: So why did you accept this answer, if it didn't fix your problem?

Comment: My original question made the assumption that there was an error in my code, but the problem was somewhere else.  So he answered my question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

So the answer turned out to be a bug in Xcode. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634580/string-parsing-to-double-fails-in-c-xcode-problem) a similar problem and its solution.